# Author of a particular field - which user modified the field

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-fields

Is it possible in Drupal to find out which user modified a particular field? Not just the whole node. After saving the content I want to display the author name next to that field.

Not sure if this is possible or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not provided by Drupal core, and (As far as I know) it is not provided by any contributed modules on [drupal.org](http://www.drupal.org/project/modules).

So, in order to do that, you would probably need to create a custom module.

A simple module to achieve that would have a database table with (nid, uid, current field value) and [hook_node_presave](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) implementation (compare field values, then update/insert/ignore saving new data to your database table).